# How to root Huawei RIO-L01 (Android 6.0.1)?

Tags: root-access, huawei

I need to gain root access in Huawei RIO-L01 phone with Android 6.0.1 (Marshmallow). I have tried installing King root, Kingoroot, Towel root and Frama root apps. All these apps failed either because the device version isn't supported or due to some internal failure. Kingorrot android app for windows doesn't get downloaded. I have also followed some tutorials online but none worked out. Mostly options require payment for acquiring the bootloader code.

Is there any method to root Huawei phone with Android 6.0.1 without purchasing boot unlocker codes?

The links that I have gone through are the following:

https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/root-with-twrp-recovery-for-g8.3298392/page-6

http://www.getdroidpro.com/huawei-g8-rio-l01-m105-root-via-magisk/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jFKJEsuir8

https://root-android.kingoapp.com/huawei/how-to-root-g8.htm

Comment: just spend 4 bucks on dc unlocker?

Comment: I think the answer is "no", check [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190/50837).