# How can unlock the bootloader on the Honor 8C without unlock code?

Tags: bootloader-lock, unrooting

The article describes how to unlock bootloader on honor-8c.

```
https://www.techdroidtips.com/honor-8c-unlock-bootloader/
```

The last step is

```
And now to apply for your Honor 8C unlock code, fill in the necessary details ie, Product Model, Product Serial Number, Product IMEI or MEID, Product ID, and Verification code.
```

I have apply for my unlock code,the huawei official technician says that it can't provider unlock code for long time.Is there another way to unlock the bootloader or root my Honor-8C then?

Comment: As far as I know there is no waw to unlock bootloader without that code. As Huawei has stopped giving out these codes there were some "code sellers" for some time but now they have fun out of codes and Huawei/Honor devices can't be unlocked anymore.

Comment: unlocking bootloader forces factory reset, are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: [supported models](https://www.dc-unlocker.com/supportedmodelshcu.php): BKK-AL00,  BKK-L21, BKK-LX1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/can-we-consider-huawei-phones-as-unrootable)