# Will dumping the partition to enable `oem unlock` and flashing back the edited partition work for unlocking the bootloader on Huawei devices?

Tags: huawei, partitions, bootloader-lock, frp, ext4

I'm trying to unlock the bootloader/FRP of several Huawei devices.
But it is difficult because there is no support from the manufacturer and the `oem unlock` is not present in the system. So, I have come with the next method:

Since the main partition is formatted with `erofs`

- Compile the kernel module (for Linux) to enable support of
  the partition.
- Next, dump the whole partition into an image file.
- Change the format into one editable.
- Mount an edit the `/system/build.prop`, to enable `oem unlock` option.
- Flash back the edited partition.
- Try to unlock the FRP/bootloader.

Does this method have viability? Or I'm missing something?

Alternatively, the whole partitions system can be dumped and flashed again, but I can convert the `erofs > ext4.`

This last one, AFAIK, should pose no problem, but since I'm not too used to android (EMUI8/9/10) well.

Comment: So you have root access using an exploit? Because overwise dumping an partition image or flashing something modified is impossible.

Comment: you can't boot unsigned ROM on locked bootloader, so your idea is pointless. you can try to unlock bootloader by modifying `devinfo` instead. regarding FRP just wipe frp partition

Comment: what is problem with PotatoNV?

Comment: @Robert, well thats why I'm asking, In not too versed in android system.

Comment: @alecxs , do you know some documents or site explaining more the FRP? Its like the UEFI? Im trying to study the devinfo. Thanks.

Comment: https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset-protection/info

Comment: check the link to alephsecurity.com https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=4100897

Comment: this is how I unlocked Huawei bootloader
https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190