# Roll back to Root on Huawei Honor View 10

Tags: rooting, huawei, bootloader-lock, emui

I have Huawei Honor View 10 phone
I got it bootloader unlocked and rooted with magisk while bootloader unlock option was available on Huawei website.

After sometime I upgraded to Android 10 update (EMUI) from Huawei which caused me to lose root.

If I rollback to previous version...

1. Do I get bootloader unlocked as earlier
2. Will it be rooted or require me to root it again

looking to hear from someone who has been there done that.

Comment: Android have a built-in downgrade/rollback protection. Once an update has been installed it will stay.

Comment: https://www.xda-developers.com/huawei-honor-bootloader-unlock-potatonv

Comment: @Robert Huawei HiSuite Desktop App has rollback feature. We are not talking about android rollback protection but Huawei specific feature.

Comment: @alecxs unfortunately honor view 10 is not in supported list of devices

Comment: @alecxs have you rolled back using hisuite?

Comment: I don't own Honor V10. Kirin 970 is not in ***tested** devices* (non-exhaustive) list - did you try it? what was the error message? it is listed in [HCU-Client](https://www.dc-unlocker.com/supportedmodelshcu.php) so other unlock method will work at least

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/232190/can-we-consider-huawei-phones-as-unrootable)

Comment: @alecxs It is pretty much rootable because I had it rooted. And NO it does not answer my question, but thanks for trying to reply even though you have neither the phone nor the experience of rolling back huawei devices. thanks !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133923/discussion-between-mohsyn-and-alecxs).