# How to root Huawei Nova Y90?

Tags: rooting

I have one Huawei Nova Y90.  When I get into the bootloader it shows "bootloader locked". When I execute the command `fastboot flashing unlock` I get this output:

```
FAILED (remote: 'Flashing Unlock is not allowed')
fastboot: error: Command failed.
```

I could not find OEM unlock option in Developer Settings.

I want to root my phone without unlocking the bootloader. How do I do that? I tried gaining root access using Kingroot, Kingoroot (Oneclick root)  but none of them worked.

Comment: Please read https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190/2241 on Huawei and rooting. But that may only be applicable to older phones. In general if you consider rooting Huawei devices are the wrong choice.