# Issues Rooting a Huawei Mediapad T1 10

Tags: rooting, tablet, huawei, bootloader-lock, mediatek

I have a Huawei Mediapad T1 10 (model T1-A21w) that I want to root since it has a modified old EMUI; i'm trying to install a basic Android 4 or wharever.

I've tried with MTKroot already and manually with CMD (im in Win10-11) and i always get stuck on the bootloader, as its locked and cant seem to find a way to unlock it.
I've read around about some codes that are needed for the unlocking, but havent seem to find any, and in the tablet itself the bootloader stays stuck.

any ideas?

Comment: My suggestion is to leave it alone. It's a very old tablet.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have a general question about the same situation: [Can we consider Huawei phones as unrootable?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/232190/44325). Hope it helps.